# How to specify agent requirements for tool plugin?

Tags: teamcity

I want to create a tool plugin which requires .NET Framework on the agent.
TC docs describe `<dependencies>` section. As far as I understood I can reference only TC's artifacts or tools.

But how can I require agent capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the build runner that should set requirements. E.g., if you also write a TeamCity runner to use the tool, you could do it from the runner's code. Otherwise, if the tool is to be used via the commandline runner, a user will have to set agent requirements explicitly (to select agents that have the tool)